# What is the meaning of 附件 here?

Tags: meaning

What do they mean by '铅笔附件‘ and '配套件‘？

'铅笔附件‘ maybe: the box that the pencils come in? Or the lead in the pencil, in case it contains harmful chemicals?

宁波检验检疫人员提醒文具出口企业，要重视铅笔附件和配套件的安全性能。

Answer (score 6):

It just means that some widgets or accessories for pencil. "附近" and "配套件" make a general reference. More time they won't be indicate what certain things they are. So don't think too much.

Comment: You mean like decorative things attached to the pencil? Fluffy balls, things on springs, suchlike?

Comment: @Pedroski Not necessarily decorative, they can be functional add-ons to the pencil such as extender, eraser tip (replacing the writing tip), etc., or even another tool that usually work together with pencils such as eraser and pencil sharpener.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy the hand phone, so the 附件 include, charger, earphone, these things called 附件.

Comment: Aha, thanks. A little correction, just to help. "When you buy a hand phone,  the 附件 may include, charger, earphone, and these things are called 附件."

Answer (score 0):

In this case,
铅笔附件 ~ 配套件

[image]
Mobile phone  accessories (eg, headphone, )

= mobile phone 附件

= imobile phone 配套件